# MissingMethodException while calling Groovy closure inside closure

Tags: groovy

I have a groovy script which looks similar like below:

```
def clouser = {
    def clouserOne = { _argsA  -> 
        def clouserTwo = { _argsB ->
            // Do Something with _argsA and _argsB
            println(_argsA)
            println(_argsB)
        }
    }
}
```

while calling this

```
clouser().clouserOne("A").clouserTwo("B")
```

I am getting an error

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Script1.clouserOne() is applicable for argument types: (String) values: [A]
    at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:11)
```

What is the correct way to define this kind of closure inside closure? And how to call it in a proper way?

Comment: Well! I think I found the answer. You no need to specify `def` in the inner Clouser.

Comment: I am not sure, why you have changed the originally closed question to something totally different.  You start now down-voted and closed from what seems to be a resonable question.

Comment: The edited question was a mistake from my end and was having less explanation.

Comment: Oh, I see. It actually is related - it's just so rare, that a closed question turns around properly. So it should re-open soon...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the original code is, that you are defining just some
local variables, that never get used.  Instead the assigned closure is
returned directly.

To make your original code work, you can call:

```
closure()("A")("B")
```

(Each closure call returns the next closure and you just chain the
calls; of course there is no need to have the `def clouserXXX` in
there).

If you leave the *only* `def` out, you will create "global vars" and that is
most likely not what you want.

If you want to have the names in there, you have to return something
with the names.  One simple example is using maps as the return.  E.g.:

```
def closure = { ->
    [closureOne: { _argsA  -> 
        [closureTwo: { _argsB ->
            println(_argsA)
            println(_argsB)
        }]
    }]
} 

closure().closureOne("A").closureTwo("B")
```

Comment: Awesome! This is one way to achieve the expectation.

Answer (score 0):

After some more reading, I came across more complex closure of closure which will accepts a closure and get executed inside closure. 
For example:

```
someClouser = {_args -> _args }

clouser = {
    clouserOne = { String _argOne -> 
        clouserTwo = { String _argTwo, Closure c={any()} -> 
            print "Use _argOne: ${_argOne} and _argTwo : ${_argTwo} and invoke passed clouser ${c.call()} this way" 
        }
    } 
}.call()
```

and it can be call or use like

```
clouser.clouserOne("IMAGE").clouserTwo("INSIDE") ​{ 
     someClouser "Hello World" 
}​​​
```

The result will be

```
Use _argOne: IMAGE and _argTwo : INSIDE and invoke passed clouser Hello World this way
```